# On navigating to native viewcontroller from flutter all ui layout overlaps with iOS status bar how to prevent it?

Tags: swift, flutter

```
let controller: FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
controller.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true

let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
let deviceChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "test", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
deviceChannel.setMethodCallHandler({ [self] (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in methodName = call.method if call.method == " test"{                                                                                                        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: AppText.MAIN_STORYBOARD, bundle:nil) let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TestViewController") as! TestViewController self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController navigationController.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: false)

        }
})
```

This is code i have written in appDelegate. This will navigate to TestViewcontroller but all ui overlaps with the ios app status bar and when i pop from TestViewController it doesn't overlap. How to solve this issues?